# Show that if $\gcd(r,s_1) =\gcd(r,s_2) = 1$, then $\gcd(r,s_1s_2) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Never mind the question. I want to try to solve that on my own. What I want to understand is how this: "Hint. $1 = ar + bs_1,\ 1 = ar + bs_2$" relates to solving it.

I'm a little confused by this statement, especially since it applies to integers.

If we say ar + bs = 1, that says to me that you have different multiples of r and s. And when you add those multiples you get 1. How can this happen unless you are adding fraction together or something, or one expression equals 1 while the other equals 0?

Comment: do you know $\gcd (r,s)=1 \iff 1 = ar + bs$ for some a and b *integers*?

Comment: @user1, Isn't that Bezout's Lemma?

Comment: yeah, I know, that's what I keep hearing, but I don't understand why that is the case

Comment: Yes, sometimes called Bezout's identity, although it isn't an identity.

Comment: And there isn't a proof in your book/course material/whatever you are studying that gave you this problem? @user226106

Comment: see [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_Lemma) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)

Comment: Not that I have seen. Professor used it a few times. I just want to get some intuition as to why it is true. If we are working with integers only, adding multiples of those integers equaling 1 seems counter intuitive to me

Comment: Example $a=9$ and $b=16$. Note that $(a)(9)+(b)(-5)=1$.

Comment: You don't really need fractions $$(3)(2) + (5)(-1) = 1$$

Comment: ooooooh. negative numbers. I guess the a or b can be negative as well

Comment: Thank you so much, I get it.

Answer (score 1):

Integers can be negative, too. You can have $2 \times 5 + ( -3) \times 3= 1$ for example.

Answer (score 0):

if d = gcd(r,s[1]) then we can write d as a linear combination of r and s[1]. This comes out of Euclid's algorithm for finding the gcd of two integers, or alternatively you can prove that the gcd of r and s[1] is the smallest positive integer of the set of all linear combinations {ar + bs[1] : a,b integers}. Given this fact, if we have:

1 = a[1]*r + b[1]*s[1] and 1= a[2]*r+b[2]*s[2] for some a[k], b[k] (here I think the a's and b's are not necessarily the same in both equations)

Then multiplying both equations together we have:

1 = a[1]*a[2]*r^2+(a[1]*b[2]*s[2]+a[2]*b[1]*s[1])*r+b[1]*b[2]*s[1]*s[2]

Hence anything that divides r and s[1] and s[2] divides 1 which proves the claim.

Does that help? The key thing is that you can always write the gcd of 2 integers as a linear combo of them both, eg: 1 =  7 x 7 - 4 x 12 where gcd(7,12) = 1

All books on elementary number theory will demonstrate this, a classic is:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Higher-Arithmetic-Introduction-Numbers/dp/0521722365

cheers